# Get all values of custom settings object

Tags: apex, customsetting

I am not able to retrieve all values from custom settings object.My custom settings object API name is Products_ID_Without_AOP__c.It has a custom field as Products_ID__c with name and value like below.It has currently 4 records.

```
Name=xyz,Products_ID__c=789;Name=tyui,Products_ID__c=34567;Name=abc,Products_ID__c=123;Name=pqr,Products_ID__c=456;Name=asd,Products_ID__c=5678
```

I am using below lines to retrieve custom settings object .

```
List<Products_ID_Without_AOP__c> listCodes = Products_ID_Without_AOP__c.getAll().values();
system.debug('value of all codes ::: '+listCodes );
```

I am getting below in debug statement :

```
value of all codes ::: (Products_ID_Without_AOP__c:{LastModifiedDate=2016-09-27 16:06:04, IsDeleted=false, CreatedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, CreatedDate=2016-09-27 16:06:04, Id=a1YW0000000iBnWMAU, CurrencyIsoCode=CAD, LastModifiedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, SetupOwnerId=00DW0000008sTVQMA2, Name=xyz, SystemModstamp=2016-09-27 16:06:04, Products_ID__c=789}, Products_ID_Without_AOP__c:{LastModifiedDate=2016-09-27 16:06:36, IsDeleted=false, CreatedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, CreatedDate=2016-09-27 16:06:36, Id=a1YW0000000iBngMAE, CurrencyIsoCode=CAD, LastModifiedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, SetupOwnerId=00DW0000008sTVQMA2, Name=tyui, SystemModstamp=2016-09-27 16:06:36, Products_ID__c=34567}, Products_ID_Without_AOP__c:{LastModifiedDate=2016-09-27 16:05:31, IsDeleted=false, CreatedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, CreatedDate=2016-09-27 16:05:31, Id=a1YW0000000iBnMMAU, CurrencyIsoCode=CAD, LastModifiedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, SetupOwnerId=00DW0000008sTVQMA2, Name=abc, SystemModstamp=2016-09-27 16:05:31, Products_ID__c=123}, Products_ID_Without_AOP__c:{LastModifiedDate=2016-09-27 16:05:48, IsDeleted=false, CreatedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, CreatedDate=2016-09-27 16:05:48, Id=a1YW0000000iBnRMAU, CurrencyIsoCode=CAD, LastModifiedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, SetupOwnerId=00DW0000008sTVQMA2, Name=pqr, SystemModstamp=2016-09-27 16:05:48, Products_ID__c=456}, Products_ID_Without_AOP__c:{LastModifiedDate=2016-09-27 16:06:14, IsDeleted=false, CreatedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, CreatedDate=2016-09-27 16:06:14, Id=a1YW0000000iBnbMAE, CurrencyIsoCode=CAD, LastModifiedById=005W0000001dzlzIAA, SetupOwnerId=00DW0000008sTVQMA2, Name=asd, SystemModstamp=2016-09-27 16:06:14, Products_ID__c=5678})
```

But i want to get values of Products_ID__c in list type.Any way to get only Products_ID__c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want a collection of the values from one field, you need to loop through the records. You can use `Set` or `List` depending on your needs, but I usually find that `Set` is better suited to the task.

```
Set<String> productIds = new Set<String>();
for (MySetting__c setting : MySetting.getAll().values())
    productIds.add(setting.ProductIdField__c);
```